# Seconds since Timestamp in VBscript?

Tags: vbscript, timestamp

I have at Timestamp like this: 21-04-2021 12:34:14.733.
I would like to write seconds since Timestamp to a variable.

How do I convert the timestamp, so this code will work?

```
Dim Seconds
Seconds = DateDiff("s",TimeStamp,Now())
```

Comment: Remove the `.733` first?

Comment: How can I get rid of the miliseconds? I have not found a solution for this.

Comment: `left(TimeStamp, len(TimeStamp)-4)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution that works. Now I get Seconds since TimeStamp.
Split removes millisecond's from source timestamp.

```
Dim Sp, Seconds
Sp = Split(TimeStamp, ".")
TimeStamp = Sp(0)
Seconds= DateDiff("s",TimeStamp, Now())
```

Answer (score -2):

Considering a variable my_var: 
DateDiff("s",#21-04-2021 12:34:14.733#,my_var)

Or if you want to get rid of milliseconds:
Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")

Comment: How can I get rid of millisecond's? I can not use the Format()

Answer (score -2):

I would use the Left function to only get the first two characters from Seconds.

```
Dim Seconds
Seconds = DateDiff("s",TimeStamp,Now())
Seconds = Left(Seconds,2)
Msgbox(Seconds)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_left.asp

Comment: Thanks, but I need seconds since Timestamp.

Comment: @jthyge sorry just updated my answer, try `Seconds = Left(Seconds,2)`